# Does 'appear' have an object here? - 1932 US?

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese, ambiguity

[Source:](http://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/287/45) *Powell v Alabama* (1932)

> It thus will be seen that, until the very morning of the trial, no
>   lawyer had been named or definitely designated to represent
>   the defendants. Prior to that time, the trial judge had
>   "appointed all the members of the bar" for the limited
>   "purpose of arraigning the defendants." Whether they would
>   represent the defendants thereafter if no counsel appeared in
>   their behalf was a matter of speculation only, or, as the judge
>   indicated, of mere anticipation on the part of the court. Such a
>   designation, even if made for all purposes, would, in our
>   opinion, have fallen far short of meeting, in any proper sense,
>   a requirement for the appointment of counsel. How many
>   lawyers were members of the bar does not **appear**, but, in the
>   very nature of things, whether many or few, they would not, thus collectively named, have been given that clear
>   appreciation of responsibility or impressed with that individual
>   sense of duty which should and naturally would accompany
>   the appointment of a selected member of the bar, specifically
>   named and assigned.

Is **appear** transitive or intransitive here? In what does the 'lawyers ... members of the bar' **appear**?

Comment: I read "How many lawyers were members of the bar does not appear" as another way to say "How many lawyers were members of the bar is not known."

Comment: or possibly, more literally, does not appear [was not specified] on the list of lawyers we looked at earlier.

Answer (score 2):

**appear** is always **intransitive.**

If viewed as a logical sequence, we get:

1. Prior to that time, the trial judge had "appointed **all the members of the bar**" for the limited "purpose of arraigning the defendants."
2. (The actual number of) **How many lawyers were members of the bar** (and thus appointed for the limited purpose mentioned above) **does not appear** = **is not stated** or **is not known** (for whatever reason)
3. **but...whether many or few**, they would not, thus collectively named,...

Comment: Thanks. Would you please explain what your numbering followed by > means? Also, since you used an ellipsis, is `and thus appointed for the limited purpose of...` part of the original quote?

Comment: Will you please to respond in your answer, and not as a comment

Comment: I've edited my answer to eliminate these issues, so it does seem appropriate to respond in a comment. The only ellipsis is now at the end of #3. I  don't know why the > marks were there. Maybe a formatting problem.